# Capture Video with opencv, save to ffmpeg pipe and live stream

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video, ffmpeg, live-streaming

The goal is to stream an analysed live video over RTSP to some media server. To make the edits/analysis I use opencv, save the edited frames as JPEG in an FFMPEG image pipe and use the same FFMPEG to create a RTSP stream. Sorry if the terminology is not that accurate, I find it still quite confusing.

I have the following code after quite some struggle:

```
import cv2
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from PIL import Image

# open pipe
p = Popen('ffmpeg -y -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -r 24 -i - -vcodec h264 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://localhost:8081/test.sdp', stdin=PIPE)

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
i = 0
while video.isOpened():
    i=i+1
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if ret:
        #[...do some analysis stuff]
        im = Image.fromarray(frame)
        im.save(p.stdin, 'JPEG')

        """
        alternatively
        img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tostring()
        p.stdin.write(img_str)
        """

    else:
        break

    print (i)
    if(i==1000):
        break


p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("done streaming video")
```

This runs for 124 frames (i=124) then the loop hangs and I get some message from ffmpeg where I am not sure what it is about, however it does not look like an error:

```
push frame
122
push frame
123
push frame
124
Input #0, image2pipe, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
[libx264 @ 000002076650d980] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000002076650d980] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 000002076650d980] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 000002076650d980] 264 - core 155 r2893 b00bcaf - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
push frame
```

The webcam seems to continue running but no more frames are pushed into the pipe. It looks like some buffer is filled or something. If I write directly to a video file instead of rtsp, it works. If I open the rtsp stream simultaneously with ffplay, it also works (although with a 5 seconds lag).
Anyone an idea where this is coming from and how to solve it?